# getCurrentPosition delay in Chrome but not Safari?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, geolocation

I'm having a very odd (but minor) issue with a delay in location return using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);` in Chrome but not in Safari.

Here's a fiddle explaining the barebones of what I mean:
https://jsfiddle.net/L59kj418/

I get ~4000ms on Chrome but ~30ms on Safari (make sure to run again after allowing location as the time to select will skew results). I've tested this on all my devices too. I'm curious if there's a reason/workaround or if this is a legitimate bug to report.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions) parameter and set maxAge to 24 hours or a year and see if that makes a difference. Also try setting accuracy to true.